# How to perform custom navigation through JFace Eclipse Wizard pages?

Tags: java, eclipse, iterator, jface, wizard

I have Eclipse JFace wizard with five pages. In the first, I have check buttons to select which pages are to be shown - if you check all, you will pass through the whole wizard, but you can also select only specific pages, and then only that pages will be shown.

So far, I used iterator with enum objects representing each page. I called next object of iterator in `getNextPage` function and its if..else cases to return certain pages in proper order. The problem is, `getNextPage` is called not only when **Next** button is pressed, but also when pageComplete event firing, etc. so iterator does not update its cursor when I want, and it ends up to fast. This is snippet of my assumption:

```java
else if(page == FirstPage )
{
    // iterator contains SelectedAction - enum objects representing pages
    this.pageIterator = page.getWizardPagesList().iterator();

    if(pageIterator.hasNext())
    {
        return selectedActionToPage(pageIterator.next());
    }
}
else
{
    if(pageIterator.hasNext())
    {
        SelectedAction action = pageIterator.next();
        if(!pageIterator.hasNext())
        {
         // we check if current page was last one
            setFinished(true);
            setLastPage(selectedActionToPage(action));
        }
        // selectedActionToPage converts enum object to WizardPage class
        return selectedActionToPage(action);
    }
    else if((pageIterator != null) && !pageIterator.hasNext())
    {
        return page;
    }
}
return page;
```

Especially, things I want to know are:

First, is there any other way to capture **Next** button click? I know there is `NextPressed` method in **WizardDialog** class, but I don't know how to call its instance from my Wizard class, or WizardPage.
Second, is there other way to customize navigation through pages, to go to specified pages?

Answer (score 0):

No, you should not try to intercept the Next button click that logic is private to the wizard dialog and you should not be trying to interfere with it,

You can either override the `WizardPage`:

```
public IWizardPage getNextPage()
```

method or you can override the `Wizard`

```
public IWizardPage getNextPage(IWizardPage page)
```

You may also need to override the matching `getPreviousPage` method. You must make your code work regardless of when the method is called. You are given the information about which is the current page, your code should use that to determine the next page.